# php version from function "phpinfo()" is inconsistent with the output from "which php" command

Tags: php, apache

Mac OSX preinstalled php version is 5.5.38, I have installed another version  which is 7.0.14

I get php version from web page which is called phpinfo(), it shows 5.5.38
[image]

However, I open command window ,and I type the command below:

```
MacBook-AIR-Jerry:local sooglejay$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
MacBook-AIR-Jerry:local sooglejay$ /usr/local/bin/php -v
PHP 7.0.14 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2016 23:34:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I know , the web page which is called phpinfo(), is powered by php5.5.38, which is the builded php version in my mac osx, and I also see apache http-conf, which reveals that apache loads libphp5.so

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

**question is : How can I let apache know that, hey man, php versioin is 7 not 5 ?**

Comment: Try to comment out the line in httpd.conf

LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Comment: thanks for your favor, I have already solved it, thanks to @Iurii Drozdov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

you should change *libexec/apache2/libphp7.so* to real path on your system.(might look like /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have both versions installed. [this](https://danielarancibia.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/installing-apache-2-4-and-php-7-for-development-on-windows/) is a good resource - even though it's on windows it tells you the configurations you need to change.

Look for `Apache24\conf\httpd.conf` and search for lines similar to these (you found 1!):

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
>
> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
>
> LoadModule php7_module "path/to/php7/php7apache2_4.dll"
>
> PHPIniDir "c:/php7"

You will have these with php5, except maybe the first two which would be similar/same. Change the versions as needed.